# Defining python variables for the elements of two matrices

Tags: python, variables, matrix

Python : I have two matrices let's call them theta and x. The elements of both the matrices are unknown, but are of type int. Now I want to equate product of this two matrices to another matrix Y whose all the elements are known and are of type int.  My question is how to define the element(variables of type int) of theta and x so that when i equate product of theta and x to y, I get all the values of elements of x or theta  when i print x or theta.

EDIT: Here are the code snippets 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByzioPhSupTnV296T0l1OWpreEE

First I created two lists x1 and theta1 and modified all the elements with symbols( sympy.symbol). Then converted the lists in the matrices x(dimension 89*3) and theta(dimension 1233*3). I multiplied theta and x_transpose to get matrix named product. Then I equated all the non-zero elements of matrix named matrix_used to the elements of product. When I printed product matrix finally I got the matrix shown in last image. So here the values of all the elements of theta and x were not stored. When I equate the 'product' to 'matrix_used', I want the values of elements of x and theta to get stored in those matrices. What type of variables(and how) should I declare so that individual values of elements of theta and x get stored.

Please help !!
Thank you !!

Comment: Any code to try out the problem?

Comment: Its still not clear about what you are expecting

Comment: I have uploaded my code in coded using ipython notebook to the link posted above.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide your code here in your question using the code blocks. It is much easier to follow code posted here rather than screenshots of code. Please also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve